# why does using repo sync cannot get source code?

Tags: android, android-manifest, git-config, repo

Recently I'm trying to use repo to download private android codes from vendors. They provided me with the .netrc and gitconfig like:

```
...
[protocol]
  version = 2
[url "https://private.xxx.yyy.cn"]
    insteadOf = ssh://git.xxx.org:9222
...
```

I think it works because under above config, I can `repo init -u https://private.xxx.yyy.cn/private_PROJECT/manifest.xml -m ABC.xml` successfully but failed without above config.

However, when I `repo sync -c --no-tags -j4`, it will report warning:

```
Fetching:  0% (0/763) warming up
Invalid clone.bundle file; ignoring
Invalid clone.bundle file; ignoring
```

I searched above warnings and I think maybe this warning doesn't matter but when I run `repo status` and current folder has only .repo but nothing else!

```
project art/
  missing (run "repo sync")
project build/blueprint/
  missing (run "repo sync")
project build/make/
  missing (run "repo sync")
project cts/
  missing (run "repo sync")
project dalvik/
  missing (run "repo sync")
```

Then I checked `.repo/manifests/ABC.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  <remote fetch="ssh://git.xxx.org:9222/private_PROJECT/" name="caf" review="codeaurora.org"/>
```

I noticed that in the manifest.xml, `remote fetch` pointed to original url instead of the proxy url, so I tried to update this xml with the proxy url.Then I tried to `repo init` & `repo sync` again.
Before update manifest.xml `cat projects/art.git/config`:

```
...
[remote "caf"]
        url = ssh://git.xxx.org:9222:9222/private_Project/platform/art
        review = codeaurora.org
        projectname = platform/art
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/caf/*
```

After update manifest.xml `cat projects/art.git/config`:

```
[remote "caf"]
        url = https://xxx.yyy.cn/private_Project/platform/art
        review = codeaurora.org
        projectname = platform/art
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/caf/*
```

It seems that it will work! Unluckily, still not work.

So I tried to just `git clone url = https://xxx.yyy.cn/private_Project/platform/art` or `git clone ssh://git.xxx.org:9222:9222/private_Project/platform/art`, I can pulled it.
I also tried to `repo sync platform/art -c --no-tags -j4`, it can also pulled it.

But there are almost 1000 sub-project in android, I don't want to run such cmd for each sub-project or work around such as creating a script. I want to know the reason why `repo sync` doesn't work here.

So, can anyone help me to figure it out?